# dynamic header CSVParser

Tags: java, csv, parsing, apache-commons

Below code parses the CSV records if the header is always known in advance and we can declare the array values for FILE_HEADER_MAPPING.

```
CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(FILE_HEADER_MAPPING);
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("file");
CSVParser csvFileParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFileFormat);
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = csvFileParser.getRecords();
```

but how to create the CSVParser for the CSV files in which the headers differs for each csv file.

I will not know the header of the csv file to create with the format

```
CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(FILE_HEADER_MAPPING);
```

I want to have a csv parser for each possible csv headers.
Please help me to solve this scenario.

Comment: i guess this is the apache commons CSV parser?

Comment: yes it is apache csv parser.

Comment: Have you read about the header auto detection?
 that could maybe solve your issue:
 https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Header_auto_detection

Comment: but.. in which version we have this method

Comment: am getting compiler error.. for Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRowAsHeader().parse(reader);

Comment: Try `CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(reader)` there is a typo in the user guide. (see [CSV-193](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CSV-193))

Comment: @SubOptimal Yes.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
package dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.source.impl;

import static dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.task.impl.BackOfficeCSVHelper.AMOUNT;
import static dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.task.impl.BackOfficeCSVHelper.FCN;
import static dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.task.impl.BackOfficeCSVHelper.FEE_TYPE;
import static dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.task.impl.BackOfficeCSVHelper.LINE_TYPE;
import static dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.task.impl.BackOfficeCSVHelper.LINE_TYPE_VALUE_CARRY_EVT;
import static dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.task.impl.BackOfficeCSVHelper.MARKIT_ID;
import static dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.task.impl.BackOfficeCSVHelper.VALUE_DATE;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import com.csvreader.CsvReader.CatastrophicException;
import com.csvreader.CsvReader.FinalizedException;

import dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.source.SourceException;
import dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.model.portfolio.Portfolio;

@Deprecated
public class CarryEventStreamSource extends AbstractInputStreamSource<CarryEventData> {

    private static String [] headers = {LINE_TYPE,VALUE_DATE,MARKIT_ID,FEE_TYPE,AMOUNT};


    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;

    public CarryEventStreamSource(InputStream stream) {
        super(stream);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    }

    public CarryEventData readNextElementInternal() throws SourceException, IOException, CatastrophicException, FinalizedException {

        //skipping all events which are not Carry
        boolean loop = true;
        while (loop) {
            // skipping all events which are not Carry
            if(getReader().readRecord() && !getReader().get(LINE_TYPE).trim().equals(LINE_TYPE_VALUE_CARRY_EVT)) {
                loop = true;
            } else {
                loop = false;
            }
        }
        //EOF?
        if (getReader().get(LINE_TYPE).trim().equals(LINE_TYPE_VALUE_CARRY_EVT)) {
            CarryEventData toReturn = new CarryEventData();
            toReturn.setComputationDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            try {
                toReturn.setValueDate(getDateFormat().parse(getReader().get(VALUE_DATE).trim()));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new SourceException(e);
            }
            if (!getPortfolio().getMtmSourceType().equals(Portfolio.MTM_SOURCE_TYPE_NONE)) {
                if (getReader().get(MARKIT_ID).trim() == null) {
                    throw new SourceException("Back Office file invalid data format: the markit id is missing on line "+getReader().getCurrentRecord());
                }
                toReturn.setTrancheMarkitId(getReader().get(MARKIT_ID).trim());             
            } else {
                if (getReader().get(FCN)==null || "".equals(getReader().get(FCN).trim())) {
                    throw new SourceException("Back Office file invalid data format: missing loan tranche id on line "+getReader().getCurrentRecord());             
                }
                toReturn.setTrancheMarkitId(getReader().get(FCN).trim());               
            }
            if (getReader().get(FEE_TYPE).equals("")) {
                toReturn.setFeeType(null);
            } else {
                toReturn.setFeeType(getReader().get(FEE_TYPE).trim());              
            }
            if (getReader().get(AMOUNT)==null) {
                throw new SourceException("Back Office file invalid data format: missing amount on line "+getReader().getCurrentRecord());              
            }
            try {
                toReturn.setAmount(new BigDecimal(getReader().get(AMOUNT)));
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                throw new SourceException(ex,"Back Office file invalid data format: invalid amount on line "+getReader().getCurrentRecord());                               
            }
            return toReturn;
        }

        // no carry found, null is returned
        return null;
    }


    public SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {
        return dateFormat;
    }

    public void setDateFormat(SimpleDateFormat dateFormat) {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    @Override
    public char getDelimiter() {
        return ',';
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getHeaderSet() {
        return Arrays.asList(headers);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "File import";



        package dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.source.impl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import com.csvreader.CsvReader.CatastrophicException;
import com.csvreader.CsvReader.FinalizedException;

import dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.engine.source.SourceException;
import dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.model.common.LTCurrency;
import dfi.fin.dcm.syn.loantrading.model.engine.event.CurrencyEvent;

public class SpotForexRateStreamSource extends AbstractInputStreamSource<CurrencyEvent> {

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

    private static String [] headers = {"CURRENCY","DATE","MID"};

    public SpotForexRateStreamSource(InputStream stream) {
        super(stream);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    }

    @Override
    public CurrencyEvent readNextElementInternal() throws SourceException, IOException, FinalizedException, CatastrophicException {
        //skipping all events which are not Trade
        if (getReader().readRecord()) {
            CurrencyEvent event = new CurrencyEvent();
            //retrieving the currency 
            LTCurrency currency = getCurrencyDAO().getLTCurrencyByISOCode(getReader().get("CURRENCY"));
            event.setCurrency(currency);
            try {
                event.setDate(getDateFormat().parse(getReader().get("DATE")));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new SourceException(e, "Parse error while reading currency event date");
            }
            event.setExchangeRate(new BigDecimal(getReader().get("MID")));
            event.setComputationDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            return event;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public char getDelimiter() {
        return ';';
    }

    public SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {
        return dateFormat;
    }

    public void setDateFormat(SimpleDateFormat dateFormat) {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getHeaderSet() {
        return Arrays.asList(headers);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CSV File";
    }

}

    }


}
```